# Grails + Weceem + Tomcat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor

Tags: tomcat, grails, weceem

I'm using Grails 2.1.5 + Weceem for CMS and Tomcat 7.0.40 as Servlet Container.

Our server has 7.5 Gb RAM and configured this JAVA_OPTS for the tomcat:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-d64 -server -Xms6144m -Xmx6144m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnsyncloadClass -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -XX:NewRatio=8"
```

Currently we got this errors in catalina.out:

```
2013-09-27 21:27:14,928 [catalina-exec-715] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:30:11,676 [catalina-exec-561] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:30:20,750 [catalina-exec-559] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:30:11,676 [catalina-exec-555] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:30:47,987 [catalina-exec-549] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:30:29,974 [catalina-exec-697] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:30:52,524 [catalina-exec-268] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:26:01,424 [catalina-exec-674] ERROR 2013-09-27 21:31:01,703StackTrace [ catalina-exec-795]  - Full Stack Trace:
ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
Sep 27, 2013 9:28:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Sep 27, 2013 9:29:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:31:42,902 [catalina-exec-706] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
catalina-exec-549] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
2013-09-27 21:32:01,324 [catalina-exec-674] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:31:56,704 [catalina-exec-534] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
Sep 27, 2013 9:29:07 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
quartzScheduler_Worker-8] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
2013-09-27 21:33:41,856 [catalina-exec-361] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Sep 27, 2013 9:28:57 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
catalina-exec-559] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
2013-09-27 21:33:41,857 [quartzScheduler_Worker-8] ERROR simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - Error while executing the Runnable: 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersToBeExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1849)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:335)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:173)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
Sep 27, 2013 9:32:19 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Sep 27, 2013 9:31:01 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Sep 27, 2013 9:33:05 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Sep 27, 2013 9:30:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 - Full Stack Trace:
2013-09-27 21:35:00,628 [catalina-exec-772] ERROR servlet.ErrorHandlingServlet  - Problem instantiating StackTraceFilterer class, using default: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:31:33,833 [catalina-exec-697] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
2013-09-27 21:31:33,628 [quartzScheduler_Worker-4] ERROR simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - Error while executing the Runnable: 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersToBeExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1849)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:335)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:173)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:35:33,190 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - Error while executing the Runnable: 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersToBeExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1849)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:335)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:173)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:35:33,1922013-09-27 21:33:41,857 [ [quartzScheduler_Worker-5] ERRORcatalina-exec-559 ] ERROR core.JobRunShell StackTrace  -  - Full Stack Trace:
Job weceem.org.weceem.jobs.AutoPublicationJob threw an unhandled Exception: 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:35:33,191 [2013-09-27 21:35:33,191quartzScheduler_Worker-10 [] ERROR catalina-exec-706simpl.SimpleThreadPool]  ERROR  - StackTraceError while executing the Runnable:  
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersToBeExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1849)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:335)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:173)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
Sep 27, 2013 9:35:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor run
GRAVE: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
2013-09-27 21:35:33,192 [2013-09-27 21:35:33,192quartzScheduler_Worker-5 [] ERROR StackTracequartzScheduler_Worker-9 ] ERROR  - Full Stack Trace:
simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - Error while executing the Runnable: 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersToBeExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1849)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:335)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:173)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:35:33,192 [quartzScheduler_Worker-5] ERROR simpl.SimpleThreadPool 2013-09-27 21:35:33,192 [ - Error while executing the Runnable: 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:35:33,192 [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] ERROR simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - Error while executing the Runnable: 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.notifyJobListenersToBeExecuted(QuartzScheduler.java:1849)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.notifyListenersBeginning(JobRunShell.java:335)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:173)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
SEVERE:Memory usage is low, parachute is non existent, your system may start failing.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space2013-09-27 21:40:21,737 [catalina-exec-336] ERROR servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet  - HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

And in our stacktrace.log:

```
2013-09-27 21:16:57,074 [quartzScheduler_Worker-4] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:16:57,074 [quartzScheduler_Worker-4] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:16:57,075 [quartzScheduler_Worker-9] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:16:57,075 [quartzScheduler_Worker-9] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:17:52,111 [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsTaskClassJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:81)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:17:52,111 [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsTaskClassJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:81)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:17:52,123 [quartzScheduler_Worker-6] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsTaskClassJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:81)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:01,591 [quartzScheduler_Worker-8] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:01,591 [quartzScheduler_Worker-62013-09-27 21:18:01,591]  [ERROR StackTracequartzScheduler_Worker-8 ] ERROR  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:01,610 [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:01,610 [quartzScheduler_Worker-7] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:01,6102013-09-27 21:18:01,610 [ [quartzScheduler_Worker-6] quartzScheduler_Worker-7ERROR ] ERROR StackTrace simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - Full Stack Trace: - 
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:01,610 [quartzScheduler_Worker-6] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:01,610 [quartzScheduler_Worker-6] ERROR simpl.SimpleThreadPool  - 2013-09-27 21:18:01,610Error while executing the Runnable: 
 [quartzScheduler_Worker-8] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:01,610 [quartzScheduler_Worker-8] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:210)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
2013-09-27 21:18:10,806 [catalina-exec-772] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.weceem.controllers.WcmContentController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

013-09-27 21:22:48,391 [catalina-exec-793] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(GrailsDispatcherServlet.java:435)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:312)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:277)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.WebUtils.forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo(WebUtils.java:268)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlMappingsFilter.java:209)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.obtainContent(GrailsPageFilter.java:206)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh.GrailsPageFilter.doFilter(GrailsPageFilter.java:152)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:369)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:381)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:168)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

2013-09-27 21:21:57,657 [catalina-exec-726] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.weceem.controllers.WcmContentController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.logThrowable(AbstractFilter.java:116)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:70)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.weceem.controllers.WcmContentController': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.getBean(AbstractFilter.java:196)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.lookupController(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:842)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:176)
        at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Hope you can help me to find the error

Comment: Everything started after: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/quartz/SchedulerException, method: isConfigurationError signature: ()Z) Illegal constant pool index
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.quartz.GrailsJobFactory$GrailsTaskClassJob.execute(GrailsJobFactory.java:81)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)

Comment: Just my 2c: did you try `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` and -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled`?

Comment: no.. do i need to put that in JAVA_OPTS? how do this helps? thanks

Comment: Java becomes more agressive on freeing memory.